# How can I get the update coordinates from edit layer leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, angular, dictionary, leaflet

There is a polygon come from api and I need to update coordinates with edit layer by angular-draw leaflet. Here is the html,

```
<div  
    style="height: 100vh;"
    leaflet
    leafletDraw 
    [leafletOptions]="options"
    [leafletDrawOptions]="drawOptions"
    (leafletDrawCreated)="onDrawCreated($event)">
    <div [leafletLayer]="drawnItems"></div>
</div>
```

And the drawOption

```
 drawOptions :any = {
        position: "topright",
        draw: {
            marker: {
                icon: icon({
                    iconSize: [25, 41],
                    iconAnchor: [13, 41],
          iconUrl: 'assets/leaflet/marker-icon.png',
                    iconRetinaUrl: 'assets/leaflet/marker-icon-2x.png',
                    shadowUrl: 'assets/leaflet/marker-shadow.png'
                })
            },
      polygon : true,
        },
    edit: {
            featureGroup: this.drawnItems
        }

  
    };
```

---

//this one is the polygon has polyhon show up the map

```
  var polygonJson =L.polygon (select,{
      
         fillColor: result.color, 
         fillOpacity: 0.5,  
         color: result.color, 
         fill: true, 
       
      })
```

//And here I am trying to get update coordinates after click edit button

```
 var updatePolygon= this.drawnItems.addLayer(polygonJson).on('draw:editvertex', function(event){
        var poly = event.layer;
      if (poly.options.polygon) {
    var coords = poly.getLatLngs();
         poly.options.polygon.setLatLngs(coords);
        }
      })
    
      
    
      var coord = updatePolygon // I am trying to get update coordinates here
      console.log(coord)
```

In this function, **select** bring the coordinates from api and I can see the polygon on map Also, there is a edit button come from option. However, while clicking the edit button for change polygon I have seen the changing coordinates on console but can not pick the updated coordinates to send the db back. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Hi, where do you call the send function? If you see coords in console you can pass it into your send function, or maybe i don't understand something?

Comment: I call from backend by api. select and result included data